# Trying to create a list with variable and calculation in python in a loop to pass it to a binary search

Tags: python, finance

I am trying to create a list with a variable in python within a loop so that I can calculate the value of that variable through a binary search later. This is quite similar to how an IRR is calculated. Here is what I have so far but I am unable to get it to work. Can the team help me here.

```
term=20
y = Symbol('y')

for i in range (1, term + 1):       
    eqn += (1 / ((1 + y / 2) ** (30 / 360 * term)))
    data.append([eqn])
```

I want to use this `eqn` in a binary search function to evaluate the value of y:

```
def binary_search (100, eqn)
    upperbound = 10
    lowerbound = 0
    y = (lower + upper) / 2
    while upper < lower:
        if eqn < 100:
            upper = y
            y = (lower + upper) / 2
        elif eqn > 100:
          lower = y
          y = (lower + upper) / 2 
       print(y)
```

I am stuck on step 1 where I need to define a looped list with a variable itself.

Comment: Do you know if what you actually want is to store the data in a [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)? You could compute your equation for certain values of `y`. The `y`s would be keys and the results would be values.

Comment: Hi @scrollout: Can you clarify it a little more. Are you suggesting that the values within dictionary should be like
y1: 1/((1+y/2)**(30/360*term))) --term =2
y2: 1/((1+y/2)**(30/360*term))) --term = 3

Comment: Perhaps I might be. To make things a bit clearer, something like `{y1: compute_equation(y1), y2: compute_equation(y2), ...}` but only if what you're trying to do is store computed `y` values for access later. You could avoid the binary search this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sympy import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = symbols('x')
    gfg_exp = - 0
    for i in range(1,4):
        gfg_exp = gfg_exp + 1/(1 + i * x)

    print("Before Integration : {}".format(gfg_exp))

    # Use sympy.integrate() method
    intr = solve(gfg_exp, x)
    print("After Integration : {}".format(float(intr[0])))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).